# how can i set a pandas dataframe column to json string that in another column in the same df?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

**i have this df:**

```
        LINE_ID DatedVehicleJourneyRef  OriginAimedDepartureTime    VehicleRef  jsonString
    1   20755   34436807    2020-02-05 07:45:00 7309652 {"tripMessages":[{"tripMessage":[{"messageCrea...
    2   20755   34436812    2020-02-05 08:00:00 7311952 {"tripMessages":[{"tripMessage":[{"messageCrea...
    7   20755   34436799    2020-02-09 06:30:00 7303952 {"tripMessages":[{"tripMessage":[{"messageCrea...
    8   20755   34436804    2020-02-09 07:45:00 7304052 {"tripMessages":[{"tripMessage":[{"messageCrea...
    9   20755   34436809    2020-02-09 08:00:00 4360908 {"tripMessages":[{"tripMessage":[{"messageCrea...
```

that has couple of regular columns and the jsonString column.

**the json string look like this:**

```
{'tripMessages': [{'tripMessage': [{'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:02:29',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:02:06',
     'tripStopRecordId': '41a70eee-3313-435c-b149-3dda50e0366d',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:02:14.280',
     'operatorMessageId': '23501',
     'coordinateX': 35.024898,
     'coordinateY': 31.898061,
     'bearing': 106,
     'velocity': 40,
     'distanceFromStart': 864,
     'percentageFromStart': 2.0,
     'stopId': 34157,
     'stopOrder': 3,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:02:06',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': True,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34156,
       'stopOrder': 2,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:00:55',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:01:28'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 35007,
       'stopOrder': 1,
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:00:31'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:02',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:03:48',
     'tripStopRecordId': '63f873ce-2a61-4071-b71c-6f9ec352edda',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:03:55.427',
     'operatorMessageId': '23522',
     'coordinateX': 35.022548,
     'coordinateY': 31.89533,
     'bearing': 305,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 1415,
     'percentageFromStart': 3.0,
     'stopId': 35010,
     'stopOrder': 4,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:03:11',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:03:48',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34157,
       'stopOrder': 3,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:02:06',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:02:21'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34156,
       'stopOrder': 2,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:00:55',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:01:28'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:13',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:57',
     'tripStopRecordId': '676be6d6-1fe9-4c9d-8427-1b2bba47b9f3',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:56.443',
     'operatorMessageId': '23538',
     'coordinateX': 35.01641,
     'coordinateY': 31.896978,
     'bearing': 282,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 2058,
     'percentageFromStart': 5.0,
     'stopId': 34158,
     'stopOrder': 6,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:33',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': True,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 35011,
       'stopOrder': 5,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:09',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:21'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 35010,
       'stopOrder': 4,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:03:11',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:03:48'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:56',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:25',
     'tripStopRecordId': 'e5b3f25f-58d6-4246-898f-f568117a3c7d',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:41.213',
     'operatorMessageId': '23546',
     'coordinateX': 35.014976,
     'coordinateY': 31.896614,
     'bearing': 240,
     'velocity': 36,
     'distanceFromStart': 2182,
     'percentageFromStart': 5.0,
     'stopId': 35012,
     'stopOrder': 7,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:07',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:25',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34158,
       'stopOrder': 6,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:33',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:05'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 35011,
       'stopOrder': 5,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:09',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:04:21'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:41',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:24',
     'tripStopRecordId': 'c7c8596d-c26a-48eb-a9da-7ab71fe1392e',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:35.223',
     'operatorMessageId': '23579',
     'coordinateX': 35.009494,
     'coordinateY': 31.90199,
     'bearing': 20,
     'velocity': 29,
     'distanceFromStart': 4220,
     'percentageFromStart': 10.0,
     'stopId': 34154,
     'stopOrder': 10,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:24',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': True,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 35014,
       'stopOrder': 9,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:06:54',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:07:25'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 35013,
       'stopOrder': 8,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:55',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:06:33'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:09:02',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:49',
     'tripStopRecordId': 'c7c8596d-c26a-48eb-a9da-7ab71fe1392e',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:55.490',
     'operatorMessageId': '23587',
     'coordinateX': 35.009666,
     'coordinateY': 31.903165,
     'bearing': 322,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 4240,
     'percentageFromStart': 10.0,
     'stopId': 34154,
     'stopOrder': 10,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:36',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 35014,
       'stopOrder': 9,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:06:54',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:07:25'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 35013,
       'stopOrder': 8,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:55',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:06:33'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:09:49',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:57',
     'tripStopRecordId': 'c7c8596d-c26a-48eb-a9da-7ab71fe1392e',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:09:42.177',
     'operatorMessageId': '23596',
     'coordinateX': 35.009666,
     'coordinateY': 31.903165,
     'bearing': 322,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 4240,
     'percentageFromStart': 10.0,
     'stopId': 34154,
     'stopOrder': 10,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:36',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 35014,
       'stopOrder': 9,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:06:54',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:07:25'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 35013,
       'stopOrder': 8,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:05:55',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:06:33'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:11:38',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:11:23',
     'tripStopRecordId': '1c1bd092-f7bb-4dbc-a352-a14d773d4764',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:11:28.757',
     'operatorMessageId': '23617',
     'coordinateX': 35.007434,
     'coordinateY': 31.907939,
     'bearing': 20,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 4942,
     'percentageFromStart': 12.0,
     'stopId': 34148,
     'stopOrder': 12,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:11:02',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': True,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34187,
       'stopOrder': 11,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:09:49',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:10:24'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34154,
       'stopOrder': 10,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:24',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:36'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:12:41',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:12:18',
     'tripStopRecordId': '1c1bd092-f7bb-4dbc-a352-a14d773d4764',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:12:25.143',
     'operatorMessageId': '23631',
     'coordinateX': 35.007873,
     'coordinateY': 31.908266,
     'bearing': 48,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 4942,
     'percentageFromStart': 12.0,
     'stopId': 34148,
     'stopOrder': 12,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:11:02',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:12:18',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34187,
       'stopOrder': 11,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:09:49',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:10:24'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34154,
       'stopOrder': 10,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:24',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:08:36'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:16:12',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:15:58',
     'tripStopRecordId': '60a5c6ee-5e8e-4a53-b470-c7da449750bb',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:15:55.633',
     'operatorMessageId': '23673',
     'coordinateX': 35.020511,
     'coordinateY': 31.906002,
     'bearing': 132,
     'velocity': 79,
     'distanceFromStart': 6592,
     'percentageFromStart': 17.0,
     'stopId': 34001,
     'stopOrder': 14,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:14:47',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:15:07',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34172,
       'stopOrder': 13,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:13:39',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:14:14'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34148,
       'stopOrder': 12,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:11:02',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:12:18'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:12',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:18:58',
     'tripStopRecordId': '1e24ab35-3d67-403d-ad85-277ab1445ad7',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:18:55.487',
     'operatorMessageId': '23711',
     'coordinateX': 35.039604,
     'coordinateY': 31.897804,
     'bearing': 98,
     'velocity': 79,
     'distanceFromStart': 8661,
     'percentageFromStart': 22.0,
     'stopId': 34002,
     'stopOrder': 15,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34001,
       'stopOrder': 14,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:14:47',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:15:07'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34172,
       'stopOrder': 13,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:13:39',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:14:14'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:22:45',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:22:30',
     'tripStopRecordId': '5988363d-6afd-43d4-bfda-1566628a1845',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:22:28.607',
     'operatorMessageId': '23757',
     'coordinateX': 35.084419,
     'coordinateY': 31.885452,
     'bearing': 134,
     'velocity': 72,
     'distanceFromStart': 13313,
     'percentageFromStart': 34.0,
     'stopId': 64003,
     'stopOrder': 16,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34001,
       'stopOrder': 14,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:14:47',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:15:07'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:12',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:02',
     'tripStopRecordId': '5988363d-6afd-43d4-bfda-1566628a1845',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:25:55.413',
     'operatorMessageId': '23800',
     'coordinateX': 35.127159,
     'coordinateY': 31.875753,
     'bearing': 112,
     'velocity': 86,
     'distanceFromStart': 17918,
     'percentageFromStart': 46.0,
     'stopId': 64003,
     'stopOrder': 16,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34001,
       'stopOrder': 14,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:14:47',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:15:07'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:29:08',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:28:37',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:28:51.463',
     'operatorMessageId': '23836',
     'coordinateX': 35.165428,
     'coordinateY': 31.873794,
     'bearing': 102,
     'velocity': 97,
     'distanceFromStart': 21932,
     'percentageFromStart': 56.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:30:12',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:29:49',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:30:04.967',
     'operatorMessageId': '23849',
     'coordinateX': 35.170444,
     'coordinateY': 31.872436,
     'bearing': 108,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 22437,
     'percentageFromStart': 58.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:33:52',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:33:39',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:33:35.503',
     'operatorMessageId': '23893',
     'coordinateX': 35.20959,
     'coordinateY': 31.856388,
     'bearing': 146,
     'velocity': 70,
     'distanceFromStart': 26527,
     'percentageFromStart': 68.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:34:12',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:33:59',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:33:55.800',
     'operatorMessageId': '23898',
     'coordinateX': 35.210391,
     'coordinateY': 31.852258,
     'bearing': 184,
     'velocity': 86,
     'distanceFromStart': 26991,
     'percentageFromStart': 69.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:36:42',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:36:21',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:36:25.917',
     'operatorMessageId': '23930',
     'coordinateX': 35.213069,
     'coordinateY': 31.819898,
     'bearing': 202,
     'velocity': 83,
     'distanceFromStart': 30627,
     'percentageFromStart': 79.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:37:12',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:36:56',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:36:57.197',
     'operatorMessageId': '23937',
     'coordinateX': 35.212001,
     'coordinateY': 31.816329,
     'bearing': 182,
     'velocity': 18,
     'distanceFromStart': 31062,
     'percentageFromStart': 80.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:38:55',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:38:05',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:38:38.577',
     'operatorMessageId': '23957',
     'coordinateX': 35.21178,
     'coordinateY': 31.812688,
     'bearing': 194,
     'velocity': 30,
     'distanceFromStart': 31452,
     'percentageFromStart': 81.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:39:05',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:38:05',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:38:58.267',
     'operatorMessageId': '23961',
     'coordinateX': 35.21178,
     'coordinateY': 31.812688,
     'bearing': 194,
     'velocity': 30,
     'distanceFromStart': 31452,
     'percentageFromStart': 81.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T08:51:42',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:51:07',
     'tripStopRecordId': '9e7b5c56-e3b4-4c3b-8881-fcac8d40d641',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T08:51:35.310',
     'operatorMessageId': '24115',
     'coordinateX': 35.198436,
     'coordinateY': 31.798421,
     'bearing': 228,
     'velocity': 25,
     'distanceFromStart': 33657,
     'percentageFromStart': 87.0,
     'stopId': 60001,
     'stopOrder': 17,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 34002,
       'stopOrder': 15,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:17',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:17:44'}]},
    {'messageCreationTime': '2020-02-13T09:03:13',
     'messageRecordingTime': '2020-02-13T08:59:08',
     'tripStopRecordId': '1d92ee45-930d-45fa-b4a3-c52ca1c91aaa',
     'messageReceiveTime': '2020-02-13T09:02:56.943',
     'operatorMessageId': '24254',
     'coordinateX': 35.204879,
     'coordinateY': 31.788633,
     'bearing': 104,
     'velocity': 0,
     'distanceFromStart': 36095,
     'percentageFromStart': 93.0,
     'stopId': 4169,
     'stopOrder': 18,
     'stopOnRequest': False,
     'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:57:22',
     'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:58:04',
     'operatorId': 18,
     'vehicleAtStop': False,
     'previousCalls': [{'previousCall': '1',
       'stopId': 60001,
       'stopOrder': 17,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:24',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:26:28'},
      {'previousCall': '2',
       'stopId': 64003,
       'stopOrder': 16,
       'actualArrivalTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:03',
       'actualDepartureTime': '2020-02-13T08:19:08'}]}]}]}
```

**i managed to create a new df from the jsonString, using this:**

```
stdf = jsons_no_nulls['jsonString'].apply(json.loads)
df_flat = pd.json_normalize(stdf, ['tripMessages', 'tripMessage'])
```

**so this is the output df:**

```
messageCreationTime messageRecordingTime    tripStopRecordId    messageReceiveTime  operatorMessageId   coordinateX coordinateY bearing velocity    distanceFromStart   percentageFromStart stopId  stopOrder   stopOnRequest   actualArrivalTime   actualDepartureTime operatorId  vehicleAtStop   previousCalls
0   2020-02-05T08:36:07 2020-02-05T08:26:52 505c41a8-e26a-47a9-89a8-a20a42736558    2020-02-05T08:35:25.193 6546    35.209415   31.809690   218 0   31902   82.0    60001   17  False   2020-02-05T08:09:42 2020-02-05T08:09:48 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 64003, 'stopO...
1   2020-02-05T08:36:07 2020-02-05T08:27:20 ffc12172-12aa-4303-9212-dcc40af18a08    2020-02-05T08:35:25.193 6546    35.157516   31.872913   46  90  21097   54.0    60001   17  False   2020-02-05T08:24:53 2020-02-05T08:25:03 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 64003, 'stopO...
2   2020-02-09T07:04:17 2020-02-09T06:58:33 97fdf612-b375-4fff-9a7a-308c3dd869b8    2020-02-09T07:03:53.157 18691   35.137054   31.870136   110 83  19064   49.0    60001   17  False   2020-02-09T06:58:09 2020-02-09T06:58:14 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 64003, 'stopO...
3   2020-02-09T07:37:26 2020-02-09T07:22:16 ab13ad77-0a2b-4bd0-a239-9f62fd26564b    2020-02-09T07:37:02.497 18706   35.202728   31.782661   214 0   36859   95.0    3375    20  False   2020-02-09T07:21:41 2020-02-09T07:21:46 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 800, 'stopOrd...
4   2020-02-09T08:23:55 2020-02-09T07:22:16 ab13ad77-0a2b-4bd0-a239-9f62fd26564b    2020-02-09T08:23:34.113 18714   35.202728   31.782661   214 0   36859   95.0    3375    20  False   2020-02-09T07:21:41 2020-02-09T07:21:46 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 800, 'stopOrd...
```

But!!! i need the 'DatedVehicleJourneyRef' column to be also in the new df. somthing like- with a new column that represents the column i wanted, melted into the new df:

[image]

just to be clear, each row in the original df has a more than 100 records in the json string.

this is what i'v tried so far- to insert the `DatedVehicle...` column to the jason string, but with no success:

```
for i, (outer_k, outer_v) in enumerate(stdf.items()):
    for (inner_k, inner_v) in outer_v.items():
        outer_v.update({inner_k: inner_v, 'asasas':str(jsons_no_nulls.iloc[i,1])})
```

**GOT IT**, this is my solution. i'm sure there is more pythonic way to solve it but it does the work:

```
#first apply the string as json
stdf = jsons_no_nulls['jsonString'].apply(json.loads)

# than start diging threw all the layers of the nested json
for i, l in enumerate(stdf):
    for a in l['tripMessages']:
        for j in a['tripMessage']:
            j['DatedVehicleJourneyRef']= str(jsons_no_nulls.iloc[i,1]) # apply the var

# finnaly normalize the json to a pandas DataFrame
df_flat = pd.json_normalize(stdf, ['tripMessages', 'tripMessage'])
# convert to str
jsons_no_nulls['DatedVehicleJourneyRef'] = jsons_no_nulls['DatedVehicleJourneyRef'].astype(str)
# merge
df_flat_trips = (df_flat.merge(jsons_no_nulls[['DatedVehicleJourneyRef', 'VehicleRef', 'LINE_ID']], on='DatedVehicleJourneyRef')
                 .sort_values(by=['DatedVehicleJourneyRef', 'messageReceiveTime'])
                 .reset_index().drop('index', 1)
                )
```

this is the output:

```
    messageCreationTime messageRecordingTime    tripStopRecordId    messageReceiveTime  operatorMessageId   coordinateX coordinateY bearing velocity    distanceFromStart   ... stopOrder   stopOnRequest   actualArrivalTime   actualDepartureTime operatorId  vehicleAtStop   previousCalls   DatedVehicleJourneyRef  VehicleRef  LINE_ID
0   2020-02-09T07:04:17 2020-02-09T06:58:33 97fdf612-b375-4fff-9a7a-308c3dd869b8    2020-02-09T07:03:53.157 18691   35.137054   31.870136   110 83  19064   ... 17  False   2020-02-09T06:58:09 2020-02-09T06:58:14 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 64003, 'stopO...   34436799    7303952 20755
1   2020-02-09T07:37:26 2020-02-09T07:22:16 ab13ad77-0a2b-4bd0-a239-9f62fd26564b    2020-02-09T07:37:02.497 18706   35.202728   31.782661   214 0   36859   ... 20  False   2020-02-09T07:21:41 2020-02-09T07:21:46 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 800, 'stopOrd...   34436799    7303952 20755
2   2020-02-09T08:23:55 2020-02-09T07:22:16 ab13ad77-0a2b-4bd0-a239-9f62fd26564b    2020-02-09T08:23:34.113 18714   35.202728   31.782661   214 0   36859   ... 20  False   2020-02-09T07:21:41 2020-02-09T07:21:46 18  False   [{'previousCall': '1', 'stopId': 800, 'stopOrd...   34436799    7303952 20755
```

thanx

Comment: Can you please paste actual data, and not pictures? It will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Is `VehicleRef` a unique identifier throughout the initial dataframe?

Comment: no, this is the vehicle id and a vehicle can make more than one trip in this df. the Unique is the 'DatedVehicleJourneyRef'

Comment: @NYCCoder... sorry, fixed

Comment: I should have asked a better question - is there any unique identifier on a per-row basis?  I suppose the index could be it.  Anyway, point being is you just need to add whatever unique identifier to the json and then merge the two dataframes on that ID.

Comment: @elPastor , this is what i have been trying to do for the past couple of days. i added my last try to the question. thnx for your comments